# Setting environment variable to command in a script

Tags: linux, bash

I made a bash script. It reads a file contains a list of commands and runs each of them.

A list of commands is like below.

```
ENV_NUMBER=1 command1
ENV_NUMBER=2 command2
ENV_NUMBER=3 command3
```

Each line has a environment variable before command to set same name but different value to commands.

A script is like below.

```
while read line
do
  if [ -n $line ] ; then
    # run command in background
    $line &
  fi
done < comandlist.txt
```

I expect:

1. run command1 with ENV_NUMBER=1
2. run command2 with ENV_NUMBER=2
3. run command3 with ENV_NUMBER=3

But, I ran script then I got error:

```
ENV_NUMBER=1: command not found
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure you are using `bash`? It looks right.

Comment: `if [ -n $line ]` will not behave as expected when `$line` is the empty string.  In that case, the command expands to `if [ -n ]`, and `[ -n ]` will succeed (return 0) because `-n` is not the empty string.  You must use quotes here: `if [ -n "$line" ]` (or use some other test)

Comment: I prefer `[[ ... ]]` over `[ ... ]` in every case if it's available at all. It throws a syntax error with no arg. :)

Comment: Thank you all. I'll take both advices :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your logic looks good from *inside* the command file...
See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Simple-Command-Expansion

The problem is that you are loading the variable assignment into a variable, rendering it as data rather than a command, then trying to context-hack it back.

```
ENV_NUMBER=1 command
```

is not the same as

```
"ENV_NUMBER=1" "command"
```

which is what you are effectively doing.

Try this instead.

```
sed -Ei 's/$/\&/' comandlist.txt # make sure there are no blank lines first!
```

then either

```
chmod x comandlist.txt
./comandlist.txt
```

or

```
source comandlist.txt
```

This makes `comandlist.txt` the script, complete with the ampersands, which it otherwise kind of already was. Your program reads it in as data and then tries to convert it *back* to script a line at a time. Don't do that.

c.f. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

## Original answer - for reference

Are you sure you are using *bash*?
Do you have something like `#!/bin/bash` as the first line of your script?

Here's my simple example script:

```
$: cat y
#! /bin/bash
echo "x=[$x]" # using whatever is available, not setting in the script
```

Running it with no `x` value:

```
$: unset x; ./y # nothing to show, x has no value
x=[]
```

Running it with an `x` set:

```
$ x=foo; ./y  # NOT exported to the subshell! Can't see it.
x=[]
```

Explicitly setting it *temporarily* in the command itself:

```
$: x=foo ./y # this creates x in this subshell, goes away when it ends
x=[foo]
```

Running again without setting to show it's temporary...

```
$ ./y  # didn't keep from last run
x=[]
```

Explicitly exporting in the parent environment:

```
$: export x=bar; ./y # reads the exported value from the parent
x=[bar]
```

Manually overriding the exported value by supplying a temporary value from the command line:

```
$: x=foo ./y # overrides exported value of "bar" in the subshell *only*
x=[foo]
```

Running again with no special edit, using the still-exported value:

```
$: ./y   # x still exported as "bar"
x=[bar]
```

So obviously what you are doing works fine in `bash`.
As I mentioned above, maybe you are *not* using `bash`.
Make sure you have a shebang. `#!` have to be *the very first two characters in the file* for it to work - no spaces above or before, no comments, nothing.

Let us know if that doesn't help.

Comment: Left the original text in case the downvote was for something untrue in there - hopefully someone will point it out. Corrected the answer for what I suspect is the real problem.

Comment: Thank you. I understand what the problem was. Making commandlist.txt the script works and is the best way to me this time.

Answer (score 2):

See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01 for a description of the order in which a simple command is parsed.  Basically, in step 1, the line is examined for variable assignments.  Since the simple command at this point is simply "$line", there are no variable assignments.  Then, in step 2, `$line` is expanded to be "ENV_NUMBER=1 command1" and the first field is taken as the command.  The line is *not* again scanned for variable assignments, and the string `ENV_NUMBER=1` is taken as the command to be executed.

It sounds as if you want to evaluate the string "$line", in which case you would need to do `eval "$line"` rather than just executing `$line`.  But beware the common knowledge "eval is evil". Using `eval` like this is generally considered bad practice.

Comment: Thank you for clear explanation. I understand what I actually did. But I would avoid use `eval`, so I take @PaulHodge's answer.